# Automation error on Webclient.Headers

Tags: vb6

I have an error in the following code when using the Headers property:

```
Public Function UploadImage(image As String) As String

Dim wc As System.WebClient

'create WebClient

Set wc = CreateObject("System.Net.WebClient")

Call wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Client-ID " & ClientId) <------- Error occurs here
```

Comment: What kind of problem is displayed? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I have repro'd your issue as far as possible. You didn't mention what the error you were getting was, but I got:

```
Automation error -2146233079   (80131509)
```

I tried using

```
CallByName(wc, "Headers", VbGet)
```

... but that just returns

```
Automation error 440.
```

Oh well...

I looked up online, and found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487406/vb6-automation-error-on-calls-to-net-3-5-assemblies-after-the-first-calls). My guess is that because the base class of the WebHeaderCollection class is not COM Visible, this causes the error.

My work-around would be to wrap up this functionality in a small .NET component, and make that COM visible.

An example of this would be something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace WebClientWrapper
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")]
    public class WebClientWrapper : WebClient
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public WebHeaderCollectionWrapper WHeaders
        {
            get 
            {
                return new WebHeaderCollectionWrapper(base.Headers);
            }
        }
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy")]
    public class WebHeaderCollectionWrapper
    {
        WebHeaderCollection _whc;

        internal WebHeaderCollectionWrapper(WebHeaderCollection whc)
        {
            _whc = whc;
        }

        [ComVisible(true)]
        public void Add(string name, string value)
        {
            _whc.Add(name, value);
        }

        [ComVisible(true)]
        public void Clear()
        {
            _whc.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

(You will have to replace the GUIDs with your own values - use GUIDGEN.EXE).

Instantiate this component with `CreateObject("WebClientWrapper.WebClientWrapper")`

Now you would simply replace references to the Headers property to WHeaders (or whatever you want to call it). WHeaders gives you a true wrapper around `WebHeaderCollection` - you'll have to define all the other wrapped methods and properties yourself. I was hoping to define WHeaders as `public WebHeaderCollectionWrapper`, but that didn't seem to work.

Since WebClientWrapper inherits from WebClient, you should be able to use most of the properties and methods. Where you have troubles, just add new methods to the class wrapping up the functionality that doesn't work with VB.

Oh, and do remember to set the checkbox at Project Properties => Build => Output => Register for COM interop. And then reference the type library created.

Comment: so how i can make it visible?
i really need it
for using my App in vb6